# AngularJs doesn't validate a invalid dropdown selection

Tags: angularjs, validation, select

Here is a basic plunker that demonstrates the problem.

- When you set the dropdownlist/select element model to empty you receive the required error message
- But when you set the model from controller, and the model is not a option in the provided ng-options select element fails to show required. But the dropdown/select is in invalid state

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/gLtjRwkaaBOQG7YMvDav?p=preview

So how do we go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) - Scroll to the bottom to the `$error` section.

`$error` only validates attributes of the `select` tag and not the option selected.

`required` is an attribute of the select tag - thus when the dropdown is empty, the `$error` flag is set to true.

However, assigning an option that is not among the predefined options is not handled by `$error` - you have to handle this yourself using something like:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="submitForm($event)">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.submitForm = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Do your validation on the select value

    //If everything is fine, call the actual submit function
};
```

Comment: I had this solution as the last resort but seems i had taken right path without knowing it was the only path