# Angularjs dropdownlist and form validation

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with several dropdown lists and some of them may have default entries that are not valid. It's essentially the same problem that was described here:
[AngularJs doesn't validate a invalid dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025578/angularjs-doesnt-validate-a-invalid-dropdown-selection)

However, I think there has to be a reasonable way to accomplish this without having to check everything manually in the controller. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<select ng-model="thisEntry" ng-options="option for option in goodOptions"></select>
<span class="error" ng-show="goodOptions.indexOf(thisEntry) == -1">Please select a valid entry from the list</span>
```

that also sets the form invalid so the user can't submit until it's fixed .  The code above actually displays the message, but I don't know how to set the form invalid at the same time, or even in an equivalent line of code.  This seems like the equivalent of a blank entry on a form that's easily handled without having to resort to javascript code.

Comment: how about required on the select?

Comment: AD.Net - unfortunately, that doesn't work as there is a value, just not a valid one.  The select looks blank because the value isn't in the select options.