# How to access value of a select in my angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs for an application. I have several  html items in an html file. Rather than access the values using the $scope.thisValue in my controller, I'd like to be able to loop through all of the selects by tag name and then access their values. If not, is there another way to approach this problem from the angular end, looking through the $scope for this kind of information. I'd rather not have to restructure my data.

Comment: `ng-model` is probably what you should be doing.  There's a 90% chance you're doing it wrong (tm) with Angular if you want to "select by tag name..."

Comment: I'm actually trying to work around an angular issue that's detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942859/angularjs-dropdownlist-and-form-validation. I've got individual functions for each select that are currently in place and it works, but it's messy and requires a lot of code to cover all of the selects.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it the angular way and have a controller for it or else you start breaking from the angular way and this is not something you want if you want to keep things standardized.

So, you need a controller where the scope covers your specific select element. In your controller you can update the property of a angular factory. That angular factory can be injected to any other controllers that needs to be notified of changes to that property.

In the other controllers, use the `$scope.$watch` api to listen to changes to the factory's property.